# Extend Core PHP Class instead of Dependency Injection?

Tags: php, oop, class, object

I am working on an application that will have a "library" folder which will contain a homemade framework/library (session, DB, cache,config type classes) and then a "modules" folder which will contain folders for the sections of my app (ie; blogs/, forums/, account/, etc,etc)

In most of my modules (blogs, forums, etc), I will need multiple objects like cache, database, logger, config objects.  I was planning on using dependency injection for this but I am curious, couldn't I just have a Core class/object that could do stuff like my database, cache, logger, time, methods and then just extend this core class into my other module classes and have access to all these things without needing to inject them?

I am pretty new to using classes/object so I may be way off here, please explain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Classes should have a [single responsibility](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). A Core class doing caching, db access, logging and time, etc is effectively a [God Object](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/God_object) aka [The Blob](http://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/the-blob). It's an [AntiPattern](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Anti-pattern). Don't do that. Make them [SOLID](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Answer (score 5):

Extending classes makes sense if you *specialize* classes or, well, *extend* them.
It doesn't make sense and usually becomes messy if the extension has nothing to do with the original purpose of the base class.

For example, you may extend a `DbBase` class with a `DbMySql` class (specialization), or an `HtmlHelper` with an `Html5Helper` (extension).

You should not extend your `DbClass` into a `ProductsModule`. Both have nothing to do with each other. The `ProductsModule` is not inherently bound to a database, so you're mixing responsibilities that have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 1):

I also agree with Gordon.

Personally I avoid the Factory static method approach.  In essence, it's equivalent to using a global variable.   It's the Service Locator anti-pattern.

In addition to the suggested DI container, I find manual dependency injection (i.e. with using a DI container) to be a valuable approach.  There's no tool (i.e. container) that can design your classes to be loosely coupled, and I find that using manual DI is helpful for focusing on that.

[P.S. I would have added this as a comment, but I'm new and am unable to comment]

Answer (score 0):

What you **CAN** do, is creating a Factory class that instantiates and provides the single objects you need. Somthing like:

```
$db = myFactory::getDBO();
$conf = myFactory::getConfig();
$session = myFactory::getSession();
```

and so on.

Comment: A DI Container would be better suited, f.e. http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/

Comment: @Gordon this is what I mean. In Joomla's Framework it's the Factory class that provides this services... it's even called JFactory :)